# Undefined property: stdClass - LARAVEL

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make an admin page where the owner of the store can check the info from users that singed on the website, but I always get the `Undefined property: stdClass::$name` error

Here's the controller function:

```
public function listar(){
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('name')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('email')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('phone')->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get(); 
}
```

Here's part of the form:

```
@foreach ($users as $u)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $u->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $u->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $u->phone}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I just want it to be able to show this info from the database.

Comment: I forgot to unclude the compact part but I did it  -  return view('admin.usuarios.index', compact('listar', 'users'));
    }

Comment: You can edit your question to add stuff if you forgot it. There's an edit link at the bottom under the tags. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're actually running the query three separate times, overwriting the `$users` variable each time. You end up with the last one, and it doesn't have a `name` property because you only selected `phone`. You should run it just once and specify all the columns you want in `select()`.

```
public function listar(){
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email', 'phone')
                 ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
}
```

Comment: can I get info from two diffent tables and put it in the same variable like $users for example?

Comment: You can. There are various ways to do that depending on what you're doing with it. A join might be appropriate, but really depends on what the other table is, how it's related to the first table, and how you need to use it

Answer (score 0):

```
public function listar(){
   $users = //Your user model class ::all();
   return $users;
}
```

Then try to view

```
@foreach ($users as $u)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $u->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $u->email }}</td>
    <td>{{ $u->phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

@endforeach